# Freeling : Unable to compile the Java API on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compilation, java, apache-stanbol

I'm currently trying to create the Java API for Freeling in order to use it on Stanbol.
In this way, I followed all the instructions given by the Freeling documentation (here :https://github.com/insideout10/stanbol-freeling)  without success. It seems to be a problem with my JDK but I really don't know how to fix it. 
This is what I've done :

**Step A**, compile Freeling in C++ (no problem here):

**A.1**)  Install the following packages (with "sudo apt-get install") :
 - build-essential
 - zlib1g-dev
 - libboost1.48-all-dev
 - automake
 - autoconf
 - libtool
 - libboost-regex-dev
 - libicu-dev
 - libboost-filesystem-dev
 - libboost-program-options-dev
 - swig

**A.2**) Download the latest version of Freeling:
svn checkout http://devel.cpl.upc.edu/freeling/svn/trunk Freeling

**A.3**) Prepare my Freeling repository:
aclocal; libtoolize; autoconf; automake -a

**4**) Build and install Freeling:
./configure
make
sudo make install

**Step B**, compile the Java API (my problem is in this step):

**1**) Replace the freeling.i located to freeling/APIs/common/freeling.i by the freeling.i given at : [url]https://raw.github.com/ziodave/freeling-brew-formula/master/APIs/common/freeling.i[/url]

**2**) Set the parameters for the Makefile located to freeling/APIs/java/MakeFile

*My Makefile is the following* :

```
# Change these paths to match your installation
# Alternatively, you can call 'make' overriding variable values, E.g.:
#     make FREELINGDIR=/my/freeling/dir SWIGDIR=/my/swig/dir JAVADIR=/my/java/dir

FREELINGDIR = /home/saturn/freeling
SWIGDIR = /usr/share/swig2.0
JAVADIR = /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25

# you may change the package name if you want
PACKAGE = edu/upc/freeling
JPACKAGE = edu.upc.freeling

# Change your compiler, if necessary.
GCC=g++

all: freeling_javaAPI.cxx libfreeling_javaAPI.so

.PHONY: all

# Compile the C++ API
libfreeling_javaAPI.so: freeling_javaAPI.cxx
    $(GCC) -shared -o libfreeling_javaAPI.so freeling_javaAPI.cxx -lfreeling -L$(FREELINGDIR)/lib -I$(FREELINGDIR)/include -I$(JAVADIR)/include -I$(JAVADIR)/include/linux -fPIC
    $(JAVADIR)/bin/javac $(PACKAGE)/*.java
    $(JAVADIR)/bin/jar -cf freeling.jar $(PACKAGE)

# Build the Java JNI wrapper classes.
freeling_javaAPI.cxx: freeling_javaAPI.i ../common/freeling.i
    rm -rf $(PACKAGE)
    mkdir -p $(PACKAGE)
    swig -java -c++ -package $(JPACKAGE) -outdir $(PACKAGE) -o freeling_javaAPI.cxx -I$(SWIGDIR)/java -I$(SWIGDIR)/std -I$(SWIGDIR) freeling_javaAPI.i

clean:
    rm -rf *.jar *.so *.cxx *.class edu
    java -> $(JAVADIR)/bin/java
    jar -> $(JAVADIR)/bin/jar
```

**3**) Run make

And I get the following result :

```
g++ -shared -o libfreeling_javaAPI.so freeling_javaAPI.cxx -lfreeling -L/usr/local/share/freeling/lib -I/usr/local/share/freeling/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25/include/linux -fPIC


freeling_javaAPI.cxx: In function ‘jlong Java_edu_upc_freeling_freelingJNI_new_1TreeIteratorNode_1_1SWIG_10(JNIEnv*, jclass)’:
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:2995:3: error: ‘tree_iterator’ was not declared in this scope
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:2995:3: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/local/include/freeling/tree.h:47:7: note:   ‘freeling::tree_iterator’
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:2995:18: error: ‘node’ was not declared in this scope
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:2995:18: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/local/include/freeling/morfo/language.h:372:14: note:   ‘freeling::node’
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:2995:23: error: ‘tree’ was not declared in this scope
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:2995:23: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/local/include/freeling/tree.h:35:26: note:   ‘freeling::tree’
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:2995:36: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:2995:39: error: ‘result’ was not declared in this scope
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:2999:46: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:2999:49: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:2999:50: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘new’
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:3000:38: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:3000:42: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
freeling_javaAPI.cxx: In function ‘jlong Java_edu_upc_freeling_freelingJNI_new_1TreeIteratorNode_1_1SWIG_11(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject)’:
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:3007:3: error: ‘tree’ was not declared in this scope
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:3007:3: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/local/include/freeling/tree.h:35:26: note:   ‘freeling::tree’
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:3007:9: error: ‘node’ was not declared in this scope
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:3007:9: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/local/include/freeling/morfo/language.h:372:14: note:   ‘freeling::node’
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:3007:17: error: ‘arg1’ was not declared in this scope
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:3007:39: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:3007:41: error: expected ‘;’ before numeric constant
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:3008:3: error: ‘tree_iterator’ was not declared in this scope
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:3008:3: note: suggested alternative:
[...]
Java_edu_upc_freeling_freelingJNI_ParseTree_1SWIGUpcast(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong)’:
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12567:7: error: ‘tree’ was not declared in this scope
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12567:7: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/local/include/freeling/tree.h:35:26: note:   ‘freeling::tree’
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12567:13: error: ‘node’ was not declared in this scope
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12567:13: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/local/include/freeling/morfo/language.h:372:14: note:   ‘freeling::node’
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12567:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12567:36: error: ‘parse_tree’ was not declared in this scope
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12567:36: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/local/include/freeling/morfo/language.h:423:14: note:   ‘freeling::parse_tree’
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12567:49: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
freeling_javaAPI.cxx: In function ‘jlong Java_edu_upc_freeling_freelingJNI_Depnode_1SWIGUpcast(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong)’:
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12575:7: error: ‘node’ was not declared in this scope
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12575:7: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/local/include/freeling/morfo/language.h:372:14: note:   ‘freeling::node’
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12575:14: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12575:28: error: ‘depnode’ was not declared in this scope
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12575:28: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/local/include/freeling/morfo/language.h:452:14: note:   ‘freeling::depnode’
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12575:38: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
freeling_javaAPI.cxx: In function ‘jlong Java_edu_upc_freeling_freelingJNI_DepTree_1SWIGUpcast(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong)’:
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12583:7: error: ‘tree’ was not declared in this scope
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12583:7: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/local/include/freeling/tree.h:35:26: note:   ‘freeling::tree’
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12583:13: error: ‘depnode’ was not declared in this scope
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12583:13: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/local/include/freeling/morfo/language.h:452:14: note:   ‘freeling::depnode’
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12583:25: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12583:39: error: ‘dep_tree’ was not declared in this scope
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12583:39: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/local/include/freeling/morfo/language.h:478:14: note:   ‘freeling::dep_tree’
freeling_javaAPI.cxx:12583:50: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
make: *** [libfreeling_javaAPI.so] Error 1
```

If I understand, the Makefile just call the JDK and encounter error.

I tried to change my JDK with older versions (I tried with JDK7, JDK6 and SDK6) but the result is the same.

For information I'm working in a virtual machine with Ubuntu12.04 x64, I also tried to compile Freeling with Ubuntu12.04 x32 but the result is the same.

I added the following lines on my .bashrc :

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25
MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m"
JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m"
ANT_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m"
JVM_ARGS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m"
export MAVEN_OPTS
export JAVA_OPTS
export ANT_OPTS
export JVM_ARGS
export JAVA_HOME
```

I think I'm doing something wrong but I really don't know what, I spent 3 days to find a solution without success. Could someone help me ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that you are far superior than me, but I noticed that you set-up your environmental variable's path, did you also check to make sure which version of java your system is using as the default overall?

Try using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and making sure the right JDK is being used.

If you already solved this issue, I'd love to hear your solution (since you posted this awhile ago).